# Text 2 Speech works with simulator but not real device

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

I use the following code:

```
    myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: ss2)
    myUtterance.rate = 0.4
    synth.speakUtterance(myUtterance)
```

with ss2 being a valid string.

I also have an error message: imagesCategory[4437:341793] Building MacinTalk voice for asset: (null)

I tried with an ipad2 and an iPhone 5.

with the simulator it works with all.

any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: some more details. I'm using Xcode v7 beta that allows to attach to real devices. I'm loading the 9.0 AVFoundation.framework. My ipad2 is under version 8.4.1. Could it be the source of my problem? if the deployment target is 9.0, does it mean 9.0 and below iOS versions are supported?

Comment: Hi narb, I have got the same problem. Have you happened to resolve the issue since then?

Comment: My mac was a loan so I was not able to go to the bottom of the problem. Having said that I didn't get much help.

Answer (score 0):

I commented out these two lines. Now it works on the real device as well as simulator. I can't tell why though.

```
//        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
//        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
```